# How to define color in Atom editor when I have got the grammar?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I am trying to create a basic set of grammar rules for an XML-like markup using the Atom Editor.

I have looked at the documentation here: https://atom.io/docs/v0.169.0/creating-a-package

But I am still stuck.  My initial goal is to be able to have Atom color specific markup (e.g. `<category>` `<RECALL>` etc and their matching, closing tags.

The documentation talks about create the match and then assigning a token, but I am unclear where to define the color or behavior.  Here is their example.

```
{
  'match': '^#{1,6}\\s+.+$'
  'name': 'markup.heading.gfm'
}
```

For my version, I assume this would mean something like:

```
{
  'match': '\<RECALL>\'
  'name': 'markup.match-tag.gfm'
}
{
  'match': '\</RECALL>'
  'name': 'markup.match-tag.gfm'
}
```

But not sure if this is the right direction.

Comment: This seems off-topic to me. Anyone with more experience want to confirm or deny?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: It is not off-topic, but the title needs to be changed.

Comment: @nhahtdh If you say so. It still seems somewhat off-topic to me.

Comment: @nhahtdh To clarify, it feels off-topic because it seems like the OP isn't asking about code, but about where to start.

Comment: No I am asking about where to start but about the actual code to be used. I gave snippets of example.